# Почему OpenGL пропускает точки при рисовании в режиме GL_POLYGON?

Tags: opengl

Надо нарисовать двунаправленную стрелку, но при рендере, пропускаются две точки в очереди (обведены красным):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот метод('glBedin') устарел и работает очень медленно. https://habrahabr.ru/post/310790/ Здесь более подходящий вариант. Хоть начать рисовать что-то в 3d будет трудновато.

Answer (score 3):

`GL_POLYGON` разрешается использовать только с выпуклыми многоугольниками. Если многоугольник невыпукл, то результат непредсказуем.

Декомпозиция вашего исходного многоугольника на выпуклые (триангуляция, например) - ваша задача.